# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type found for dependency using annotaition

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I have such project structure:

[image: project structure]

persistence.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

<persistence-unit name="todos" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>server.entity.Holiday</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Web.xml (As you can see, I'm using context Class where I will use JSON):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="3.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     metadata-complete="false">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>server.config</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

WebAppConfig.class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("server")
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/pages/");
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    converters.add(converter);
}


@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

    return resolver;
 }
 }
```

HolidayController.class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/holidays")
public class HolidayController {

@Autowired
private HolidayRepository holidayRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Holiday> getAllHolidays() {
    //  List<User> list = userRepository.findAll();
    return holidayRepository.findAll();
}
```

HolidayRepository.class:

```
    @Repository 
    public interface HolidayRepository extends JpaRepository<Holiday, Long> {
 }
```

I've got this error:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [server.repository.HolidayRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Help me, please.

Comment: You're missing your spring bean configuration (java based or xml) or you simply haven't posted it?

Comment: I'm try to add all necessary beans to WebAppConfig.class

Answer (score 1):

I seems you need @EnableJpaRepositories in your JavaConfig

See secton 3.2 -> http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.definition

Create a new JavaConfig class:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
class JpaSpringDataConfig {}
```

Or add this to your XML config:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="server.repository"/>
```

---

Since your log says it expects a WebApplicationInitializer, remove your web.xml and include a class like:

```
public class RestWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { JpaSpringDataConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't understand in which file I have to put it.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the top of the WebAppConfig.class

Comment: If you about "@EnableWebMvc", then yes. But I still get that mistake...  I've got misunderstanding about "@NoRepositoryBean" that I found by your link.  Anyway, it seems that I forgot to add some necessary bean...

Comment: Add @EnableJpaRepositories to the top of the class, not NoRepositoryBean

Comment: Yeah, I did it, like I said) But nope..(

Comment: I have edited the answer with a example of a JavaConfig class containing the annotation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107826/discussion-between-tom-wally-and-morsor).

Answer (score 0):

Add the annotation `@Repository` to the implementation of `HolidayRepository interface.`

Comment: That's not necessary with Spring Data interfaces (and there is no implementation, because the implementation is created dynamically by Spring Data).